# Dificuldade com anotações JPA para relacionamento entre entidades

Tags: sql, hibernate, jpa

Tenho os seguintes relacionamentos: **CategoriaPeca**, **SubcategoriaPeca** e **Peca**.
Uma **CategoriaPeca** pode ter várias **SubcategoriaPeca**, e uma **SubcategoriaPeca** pode ter várias **CategoriaPeca**, uma peca pode estar somente em uma **SubcategoriaPeca** e somente em uma **CategoriaPeca**. As seguintes anotações foram criadas na tentativa de criar este relacionamento.

```
@Entity
@Table
public class CategoriaPeca implements Serializable{
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    @Id
    private Long id;

    @Column
    private String descricao;

    @OneToMany(mappedBy = "categoriaPeca")
    private List<Peca> peca;

    @ManyToMany(mappedBy = "categorias", cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
    private List<SubcategoriaPeca> subcategorias;

@Entity
@Table
public class SubcategoriaPeca implements Serializable {
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    @Id
    private Long id;

    @Column
    private String descricao;

    @OneToMany(mappedBy = "subcategoriaPeca", fetch = FetchType.EAGER)
    private List<Peca> pecas;

    @ManyToMany(cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
    @JoinTable(name = "categoriapeca_subcategoriapeca",
                joinColumns = {@JoinColumn(name = "categoriapeca_id")},
                inverseJoinColumns = {@JoinColumn(name = "subcategoriapeca_id")})
    private List<CategoriaPeca> categorias;

@Entity
@Table
public class Peca implements Serializable {
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    @Id
    @NotEmpty
    @Column(name = "cod_item", nullable = false, length = 14)
    private String codigo;

    @ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
    private SubcategoriaPeca subcategoriaPeca;

    @ManyToOne(cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
    @JoinColumn(name = "categoriapeca_id", referencedColumnName = "id")
    private CategoriaPeca categoriaPeca;
```

O que preciso é que na hora de selecionar cada **CategoriaPeca** me seja mostrado cada **SubcategoriaPeca** referente, e cada **Peca** onde o categoria.id seja igual a da categoria selecionada e subcategoria_id seja igual á **Subcategoriapeca** referente.

Ex:

> Tenho a categoria Motor que possui as subcategorias Retentor e Cruzeta, 
>   Tenho a categoria Freio que possui as subcategorias Retentor e
>   Rolamento, Tenho a peca que tem a subcategoria Retentor e categoria
>   Freio ,A peça so devera aparecer quando selecionar a categoria Freio >
>   Retentor

Comment: Mas o que está acontecendo? Não está funcionando? Apresenta alguma mensagem de erro? De imediato, acho que está faltando o @JoinColumn no subcategoriaPeca de Peca.